# how would I hook up this 9kw heater?

Tags: electrical, heater, electric-heat

I have a 9kw heater I want to hook up.  There is a 3x8 AWG (w/ ground) cable going to and from the heater's control panel.  The cable connects to a a 40 amp breaker, with the red and black on either side and neutral connected to the neutral bus, and ground connected to the ground bar.

The diagram looks like this, presumably with the `L1 L1 L2 L2` terminals taking the cable from the breaker, and the `O1 O2 O3 O4` terminals taking the cable which goes out to the heater.

[image]

**Which wires do I connect where?**

Comment: Can you post a photo of the heater's nameplate?

Comment: i don't know what that is.  this is a sauna heater btw.

Comment: Well, I don't know how your heater is designed.  So here we are.

Comment: @WalrustheCat -- the heater should have a label on it that depicts how much power it draws, etc....

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel it's 9kw as per the question.  i don't see any labeling like what you're requesting.  what information is missing?

Comment: @WalrustheCat -- if it's an actual subdivided unit, it should say how big the individual elements/element-sets are...(I'm suspecting that either it should have a set of breakers fitted at the unit, analogous to NEC 422.11(F)(1), or it needs a bigger branch circuit due to being a continuous load as per 424.3(B), but I could be wrong...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel i believe it's 3x3kw

Answer (score 1):

Apparently on contacting the manufacturer you are supposed to bridge the `L1`s and `L2`s.

Comment: The big question is "is this a continuous load?" As if it is, then you've just overloaded a 40A branch circuit...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel thanks i'm checking into it.  what could be the consequences of these two loads sharing the same return path?

Comment: I'd expect the breaker to kick before anything *particularly* untoward happens to anything else, but if there's something else messed up like a bad connection, then that could give first...