# Can two loads use the same neutral return path?

Tags: electrical, wiring, neutral

I have a [220v circuit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/163877/how-would-i-hook-up-this-9kw-heater/163951?noredirect=1#comment276176_163951) with two hot conductors.  The connection has 4 terminals, `L1 L1 L2 L2`.  The cable going in has a neutral conductor.

Can I hook the first of the `L1` and `L2` to the neutral conductor?  What are the implications of sharing the same return path?

Comment: That depends on the equipment, and also your locality. We can't say definitely that it can, or cannot, be done, without a lot of information about your particular equipment. The locality (and wiring service type) also affects the question of whether the neutral can be shared.

Comment: Where in the world are you?  From some of your previous posts it looks like you're in the US, but this sauna heater looks like it's only sold in Europe?  What country you're in will absolutely make a difference as to what is the correct way to wire it.

Comment: You are correct on both counts.  I contacted the manufacturer and he says to bridge the two `L1`s and the two `L2`s, respectively.